# PHP+JS application structure

Tags: javascript, php, web

I'm wondering how should i manage data in my application.

Currently it is like that:

A javascript script fires the post query that passes the `{"init" : 1}` once the page loads, then it fires the post query to the same file with `{"update" : 1}` every N seconds and prints the returning value to the page.

What i currently have (the code is approximate just to make it clear):

```php
if(isset($_POST["init"])) {
    $a = new A();
    $a->set(5);
} elseif (isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $a->update(); 
    return $a->get();
}
```

But this doesn't work because it says that there is no `$a` when I'm trying to `update`. I've tried making it `GLOBAL` and `STATIC`, neither helped.

How can I manage this? And how should i manage this?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you don't have access to your $a if update is set, you should also send your $a data so it will work. 
You can also use $_SESSION variables to get your $a across thoses pages and it will be managed only server side.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["init"])) {
    $a = new A();
    $a->set(5);
    $_SESSION['a'] = $a
} elseif (isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $a = $_SESSION['a'];
    $a->update(); 
    $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
}
```

I wrote more lines than needed so you understand well what i'm doing in.

Comment: I meant I wrote more lines that needed, you do :
$_SESSION['a']->update(); for example

Comment: Then you should explicitly state that.

Comment: Bad explanations from me because this isn't my native language, that's all :)

Comment: Now that's better. I would only place the variable names between backticks. Also, `SESSION` should be `$_SESSION`. Don't forget to mention that the browser needs to support cookies and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find $a by $id before your update it, for example:

```
if(isset($_POST["init"])) {
    $a = new A();
    $a->set(5);
} elseif (isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $a = A->findById($_POST["id"]);
    $a->update(); 
    return $a->get();
}
```

Also note that grab data from user without filtering is a bad practice.

Comment: No no no no, I want to have it all on the server side. Is that possible? Also in my case the only user info I'm receiving is the post query.